# How can i resize the height of UICollectionViewCell dynamically in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have one Image and one Label. Image is fix but the label is variable.
So, the size of the label may vary. 
So, i want to change the height of the cell.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
   {
            return 1;
   }

    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return questions.count;
    }
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        SymbolCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


        Question *q = [questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *image = q.ImageName;
        cell.imgSymbol.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];

        cell.lblName.text = q.Answer;


        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to return cell width and height.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        SymbolCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


        Question *q = [questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSString *image = q.ImageName;
        cell.imgSymbol.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];

        cell.lblName.frame = CGRectMake(cell.lblName.frame.origin.x , cell.imgSymbol.frame.origin.y+8, cell.lblName.frame.size.width, 21);

        NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:q.Answer];
        [str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

        cell.lblName.attributedText = str;
        [cell.lblName setNumberOfLines:0];
        [cell.lblName sizeToFit];

        return cell;
    }


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // calculate label height here
      Question *q = [questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:q.Answer];
        [str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];

       CGSize sizeName = CGRectIntegral([str boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake("YorLabel Width", MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil]).size;

    // give here cell width and height
    return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width-20)/3, sizeName.height+YourImage height + spec); // here return your cell height
}
```

Comment: I want to set the height of the cell as per the image and label. my label is below the image.

Comment: @Bhumiksoni first set image frame and then set label frame in cellForItemAtIndexPath method. and calculate label height using NSAttributeString. same label height calculation code in this method.